# How secure variables in JS/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I try to make my single page app more secure. In code I have post request witch return user information.

```
user: {
    city: "USA"
    company: "1"
    country: "Boston"
    email: "mouse@test.ru"
   favorList: "17 8 7 1"
   id: "46"
   name: "Alex"
   password: "d89885b09d30673f2a8321eeb1f8ab3bb3p6f"
   phone: "+7(000)000-09-00"
   role: "user"
   settings: "false true"
   viewingList: "8 17 143 138"
}
```

Some vields of this object I use for ng-show/ng-if/ng-hide/ng-switch managing html on templates. For example: `<div ng-if="user.role == 'administrator'"` or
`<div ng-if="user.role == 'user'"`

But user can open in chrome development tools and retype user role, then go to templates and get administator rites.

How I can fix that?

Comment: Use a server side check.

Comment: Never bring all that data from BackEnd to FrontEnd.
Always check the role on server side use session or something to know what user is logged get the user ask DB about user roles.

Comment: On server side i have such checking. User loggin => get an object. Some how I heed to manage html based on user role. So I have to pass t UI user role variable but I need to secure it some how.

Comment: If you only need the roles from user on front end, just send the roles for the user, dont send the password of the user on the object

Comment: No, you don't, you just need to pass back some form of flag. The point was that on the server side you need to re-check authorization to see if the user can take the action they're trying to take--you cannot rely on the front end to only send appropriate requests.

Comment: `But user can open in chrome development tools and retype user role, then go to templates and get administator rites.` This scares me. If a malicious user 'spoofs' admin rights then maybe a 'admin only' part of the template is displayed. However no data should be populated and they certainly shouldn't gain admin rights in your app. Any requests for restricted data should check server side for user rights. Not just rely on what the client tells it.

Comment: All actions for administrators I check by session. I wish some html users can;t see in any case exept for administrators. I try to hide extra html and secure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is by definition of a client side-script, an insure language.
Objects and functions can be altered either by injected js, or by the user directly in the browser.

Therefore it is very important not to be depending on js to secure your application. Normally the js / angular layer of your application would only provide a fancy user interface, it can contain some simple business logic or checks, but only to make things smoother or faster for the user (if you can check an email address client side before sending the address to the server, you should). However, this UI 'talks' with your server side code, and there you should have another security layer which prevents operations for which the user is not authorized.

So in short, use js for your user interface and use the speed of client side scripts to your advantage, but make sure to encapsulate your server side calls with their own security layer to prevent unauthorized calls.

There is no way to prevent tampering with your data in js, so make sure that tampering cannot leak information or change data which the user has no access to.

Regards,

Sem

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent a user from modifying the dom in their browser.

The only reason why you would expose such properties as "user role" to the client side is if  you use it to change something aesthetically. Modifying it should have no effect on how their account behaves.

Such data should be stored on the server side only in the session and/or database